# Why is my JSON SerDe not being used when I create a Hive external table on S3?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, hive

I use specify a `ROW FORMAT SERDE` when I script the creation of an external table, but then when I call `SHOW CREATE TABLE` it did not use that SerDe and the data is not parsed properly.  I am using the Proof Point SerDe jar for JSONs https://github.com/proofpoint/hive-serde.

The resulting table has JSON is put into the first column and I get nulls for the rest of the columns that I specified (which makes sense if the SerDe to parse the JSON was not actually used).

The version of Hive I am using is 0.11.0.

*What's strange to me is that Hive said that it created the table properly with no errors, but then the create statement that is returned indicates that Hive just did not use the SerDe that I specified. Why would this be and how might I get this to work?*

**Some more background on what I did and some code**:

Made sure I had to the SerDe jar:

```
locate hive-serde-1.0.jar
```

In the Hive shell, added the jar to make sure that Hive had access to it:

```
add jar /home/hadoop/.versions/2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hive-serde-1.0.jar;
```

The response to the above command indicates that it worked fine:

```
Added /home/hadoop/.versions/2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hive-serde-1.0.jar to class path
Added resource: /home/hadoop/.versions/2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hive-serde-1.0.jar
```

I then script the creation of the table:

```
create external table if not exists db.new_table(
        time string,
        type string,
        id string,
        sample_interval int
    )
    partitioned by (dt string, hour string)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.proofpoint.hive.serde.JsonSerde'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('errors.ignore' = 'true')
    location 's3n://bucket/directory_path';
```

Hive indicates that it was successfully created. To check that it was created the right way, I then call the following:

```
show create table new_table;
```

And get this in response:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE new_table(
  time string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  type string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  id string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  sample_interval int COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY (
  dt string,
  hour string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3n://bucket/directory_path'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1435182901')
```

Comment: I just ran `show create table` on a JSON external table that I have, and the `INPUTFORMAT` and `OUTPUTFORMAT` are the same as yours, so it looks like this command won't show if you're using a Serde. Can you include a sample of the JSON that you're trying to parse?

Comment: also can you try with this serde instead? https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Comment: @maxymoo, thanks for your input here, I found that I had a problem in the declaration of one of my fields - I changed it from a float to a double and it parsed fine... the fields that I posted were abbreviated from the actual create table script (like 100 fields) so the problem didn't even end up making it into the question.